# Cannot read property of undefined using componentWillMount in React with Meteor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have not been able to figure out how to get around this error. I think it has something to do with using "bind" since this is ES6. I have tried adding .bind(this) to the end of the constructor. I have also tried replacing 'componentWillMount' with 'componentDidMount'.  This is using meteor and react.

**Error:**

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'symbol' of undefined
    at Trades.render (Trades.jsx:9)

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { trades: [] };
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ trades: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        symbol: "GOOG",
        shares: 25,
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        symbol: "WMT",
        shares: 50,
      },
    ]});
  }.bind(this)

  renderTrades() {
    return this.state.trades.map((trade) => (
      <Trades key={trade._id} trade={trade} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
          <div className="container">
              <div className="col s12 m4"><Trades />
              <h2>Trades</h2>
                <Divider/>
                  <List>
                    {this.renderTrades()}
                  </List>
                <Divider/>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

**Trades.js**

```
  export default class Trades extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <ListItem
          primaryText={this.props.trade.symbol}
          leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img.jpg" />}
          />
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: try to console `this.state.trades` in your method `renderTrades`, are you getting something? also, can you please show, how are you using `bind`.

Comment: This happens because setState is an async action. Basically when setState is called the code exits cwm and hits render.  The render passes an empty trade array as data has not been set yet. And then you are accessing a property of symbol of an undefined object hence the error. You can solve it in 2 ways. 1. Initialise the state at the constructor level if its going to be static or constant or 2 conditionally render the list only if objects exist in the trade array.

Comment: @RaghavGarg It shows the list of trades. Thank you, I had been wondering how to use console.log for this problem.

Comment: @RaghavGarg Now it's just an empty array. Not sure why it changed.

Comment: @RaghavGarg In the question, I just now added the .bind(this). The app crashes when this is added.

Comment: please see the comment of @NitishPhanse, for understanding why only sometime you get the data.

Comment: @RaghavGarg  Using componentWillMount, the array includes the trades in console.log. Using componentDidMount, the array is empty.

Comment: @NitishPhanse Thank you for this explanation. I'm trying to figure how to set the state at the constructor level.

Comment: @Randy https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kt2OmW8VGxpIC8tdXyR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not good idea to use setState in `componentWillMount` ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)), use `componentDidMount` instead and check if your array is not empty in `Trades` component:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ trades: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        symbol: "GOOG",
        shares: 25,
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        symbol: "WMT",
        shares: 50,
      },
    ]});
  }

 export default class Trades extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        this.props.trade && this.props.trade.symbol? <ListItem
          primaryText={this.props.trade.symbol}
          leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img.jpg" />}
          /> : <div>loading...</div>

      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: little explanation would be nice to add.

Comment: @RaghavGarg, yep, sure.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you, but it isn't fixed yet. I made the changes to both files.  "Cannot read property length of undefined"

Comment: @Randy, I have edited. But if the in `componentWillMount` is real code and not imitation, this check is not needed at all.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you so much for taking the time. It works now.